# Creating a data frame from two dataframes with period indices that overlap but are not identical

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two data frames, each one representing an irregular time series.

Here is a sample from df1:

```
index   
2014-10-30 16:00    118
2014-10-30 19:00    160
2014-10-30 22:00    88
2014-10-31 00:00    128
2014-10-31 03:00    89
2014-10-31 11:00    66
2014-10-31 17:00    84
2014-10-31 20:00    104
2014-10-31 21:00    82
2014-10-31 23:00    95
2014-11-01 02:00    44
2014-11-01 03:00    54
2014-11-01 14:00    83
2014-11-02 03:00    78
2014-11-02 04:00    87
2014-11-02 13:00    90
```

And here is a sample from df2:

```
index   
2016-02-04 02:00    0.00
2016-02-06 00:00    50.00
2016-02-07 05:00    30.00
2016-02-07 21:00    26.00
2016-02-10 18:00    100.00
2016-02-11 00:00    20.00
2016-02-12 03:00    15.00
2016-02-12 18:00    90.00
2016-02-13 17:00    25.00
2016-02-13 19:00    40.00
2016-02-15 00:00    35.00
2016-02-18 04:00    14.00
2016-02-28 00:00    33.98
```

The indices are pandas Period objects with hourly frequency, and the range of time represented by the indices of the two data frames definitely has some overlap. How can I merge them into a single data frame that indexes by the union of their indices and leaves blanks (which I could later apply an `ffill` to) where one column lacks a value for a particular index?

Here's what I tried:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer')
```

This gave me what seemed like a nonsensical result that loses the indices:

```
    0
0   118.00
1   160.00
2   88.00
3   128.00
4   89.00
5   66.00
6   84.00
7   104.00
8   82.00
9   95.00
```

I also tried:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', left_on = 'index', right_on = 'index')
```

This gave me a `KeyError`:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)()

KeyError: 'index'
```

Finally, I tried created a new data frame with a dictionary after `resampling` each data frame:

```
df_1 = df1.resample('H').ffill()
df_2 = df2.resample('H').ffill()

fin = pd.DataFrame({'d1':df_1[0], 'd2':df_2[0]})
```

but this generates output where the `d2` column is entirely `NaN` even though the original `df_2` post resampling looks fine.

**How can I do this merge?**

Comment: Please explain as *union of their indices* is not too clear or better yet, from the two dfs show what desired output would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `merge`, try `join` in this case, as it will preserve the index:

`df1.join(df2, how='outer')`

It shouldn't need any other configuration in this case. Joining with `outer` will leave `NaN` values in place wherever a column lacks a value at that point in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Two other options:

1) use `merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

2) use `append` since the two dfs have the exact same columns then drop duplicated rows

```
df = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
```